# How to make sure fluentd BufferedOutput write(chunk) process events exactly once

Tags: fluentd

In a BufferedOutput plugin, 
if `write(chunk)` throws exception or the fluentd process dies when it is processing the chunk, according to the docs it says the chunk will still stay in the queue but does that mean the events/records processed before the crash will be processed again after fluentd restarts?

If that is the case, `write(chunk)` has to be atomic for "exactly once processing". Then, is the method written [here](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#filterstream-method) in the filterstream-method section  good for the purpose? i.e. Are the events in the `MultiEventStream` being processed atomically?

Answer (score 0):

`write(chunk)` may be retried sometimes if any errors occurs in that method. So that method should be written as idempotent.

I cannot understand what you're doing. Each methods are designed for these purposes:

- `filter_stream` in Filter: select/reject events, or enrich/shave fields of records (once per each event, not retried)
- `format` in Output: format events to string/binary, then it will be written into chunks (once per each event, not retried)
- `write` in Output: read data from chunk and write/send it to destination (at least once per chunks, retried for errors)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I know that `write(chunk)` guarantees processing of the chunk at least once but right now the problem is I don't want it to process any of the events of the chunk more than once in case fluentd dies/it throws exception during the time that `write(chunk)` is processing and already sent some data to the destination

Comment: I got your idea that a filter must be idempotent if it mutates the events. But I want to ask if there is any way to make sure the `write(chunk)` sent the mutated data (in chunk) to the destination atomically (either fail or success; will not send only half the data and retry for the whole chunk)

Comment: There is just only a way to do it - catch all exceptions in `write` without re-raise.

Comment: There is a Japanese blog about this which says the `write(chunk)` must be atomic: http://www.songmu.jp/riji/entry/2015-01-29-fluent-buffer-plugin.html

Comment: Say I have a chunk and have a plugin to process it.
I need to aggregate the data in chunk, it may be getting the sum of a key for each IP in a row of log. How do I `emit` that whole data atomically?